# How to merge multiple similar rows into unique rows in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

We have a task in hand.

Current Google Sheets look like this:

[image]

We want to make Google Sheets look like this:

[image]

**What are we currently doing?**

1. Select all similar rows
2. Click on format menu -> merge -> merge vertically

**What is not working for us?**
Our Google Sheets contains 2k rows, not possible for us to do manually for each row.

**What are we excepting?**
Some formula or solution where we can do this automatically.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. It's not clear what you are looking for. Do you want to remove the duplicates or you are looking to merge cells?

Answer (score 0):

To remove duplicates so that you get just one copy of each unique row in the range `A1:C` in `Sheet1`, use this:

`=unique(Sheet1!A1:C)`

To automatically merge rows in-place so that cells with identical values span many rows vertically, you will need a script. See the [mergeBlankCellsWithNonBlankCellAboveAndDrawBorders_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/40325828?msgid=40481133) script for sample code.